# CodeIgniter userdata For Session won't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am trying to create a blog site , i have a database named ci_test it has two table users and article . I have an issue with the session that can't fix. I set-

```
$config['encryption_key'] = '1234';
```

Also, set the property

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');
```

But it gives the error :

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Admin::$session
>
> Filename: controllers/admin.php
>
> Line Number: 18

My login code is:

```
<?php

class Login extends MY_Controller{
    
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->view('public/admin_login');
    }

        public function admin_login()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','user name','required|alpha|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','password','required');

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger">','</p>');

        if($this->form_validation->run())
        {

            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');

            $this->load->model('loginmodel');
            $login_id = $this->loginmodel->login_valid($username, $password);
            if($login_id)
            {
                //$this->load->library('session');
                $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $login_id);

                redirect('admin/dashboard');
            }
            else{
                echo 'password dont'; 
            }

        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('public/admin_login');
        }


    }
}
```

**Updated from comment login model**

```
class Loginmodel extends CI_Model{ 

public function login_valid($username, $password) {

$q = $this->db->where(['uname'=>$username,'pword'=>$password])->g‌​et('users'); 

if($q->num_rows()) { 

return $q->row()->id; //return TRUE; } else{ return FALSE; 

} 

}
```

admin controller:

```
<?php

class Admin extends CI_Controller{
    
    public function dashboard()
    {


        $this->load->model('articlesmodel','article');

        $articles = $this->article->articles_list();

        $this->load->view('admin/dashboard',['articles'=> $articles]);
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        if(! $this->session->userdata('user_id'))
        {
            redirect('login');
        }       
    }


}
```

Model:

```
<?php

class Articlesmodel extends CI_Model{

    public function articles_list()
    {
        
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $query = $this->db->select('title')->where('user_data',$user_id)->get('articles');
                
            return $query->result();        
    }


}
```

view:

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Serial no</td>
            <td>Article List</td>

            <td>#</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php if(count($articles)): ?>
    <?php foreach($articles as $article): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                1
            </td>
            <td>
            <?= $article->title; ?>
            </td>

            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php else:?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Record not found</td>
        </tr>
<?php endif;?>  
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: have added my answer hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your file name is `controllers/Admin.php` instead of  `controllers/admin.php` first letter always upper case only same applies for classes

And your construct() should all ways be below class and you are missing parent::__construct()

```
<?php

class Admin extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(); // Missing
        if(! $this->session->userdata('user_id'))
        {
            redirect('login');
        }       
    }

    public function dashboard() {

    }

}
```

I think you have set it in a group. where user_id is group name

```
$data = array(
    'id' => $login_id->column_name
);

$this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $data);
```

Accessing data

```
$id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

$id['id'];
```

> Or Try

```
$this->session->set_userdata(array('user_id' => $login_id->column_name)); //
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#adding-session-data

Make sure if your using files in Ci3 you have set your path

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 'application/cache/session/';
```

Codeigniter Encryption Key http://randomkeygen.com/

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'YyO29izmGbTj84kQPAkxkjI1Cz4Whe71';
```

### Update

```
public function login_valid($username, $password) {
    $this->db->where('uname', $username);
    $this->db->where('pword', $password);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        return $query->row();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then on the controller if login correct

```
$login = $this->some_model->login($this->input->post('username'), $this->input->post('password'));

if ($login) {
    $this->session->set_userdata(array('user_id' => $login->column_name));
    redirect('successcontroller');
} else {
     // Error
}
```

Comment: The error is moved but still there is an issue sir, the session has no value in user_id its generate an empty array, So there is no record found in view. how to solve it.

Comment: Have you set the session value like the second example in my answer `$this->session->set_userdata(array('user_id' => $login_id));` ANd make sure you have named the files correct like at top of answer

Comment: Yes sir, I do as you say, But it's not working. The  check for login also not working because session has no value,

Comment: Try something like this then when trying to get result `$this->session->set_userdata(array('user_id' => $login_id->your_column_name));` I have updated the answer.

Comment: But need to see your model for login_valid

Comment: parent::__construct();
  if(! $this->session->userdata('user_id'))
  {
   redirect('login');
  }                                                                                                                 I check here, It still show no record in the table

Comment: Can you add your login model to your question because that might be where issue is on your login model a you `return $query->result()` or `return true;`

Comment: $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
  $query = $this->db->select('title')->where('user_id',$user_id)->get('articles');
    
   return $query->result();

Comment: That is not your login model

Comment: `class Loginmodel extends CI_Model{

 public function login_valid($username, $password)
 {
  $q = $this->db->where(['uname'=>$username,'pword'=>$password])->get('users');
  if($q->num_rows())
  {
   return $q->row()->id;
   //return TRUE;
  }
  else{
   return FALSE;
  }
 }
`

Comment: It is wrong your model login funtion I will update my answer shortly

Comment: sorry sir, in this case login is not valid, it gives the error:Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php

Line Number: 669

Backtrace:

File: C:\wamp64\www\CodeIgniter-3.0.6\application\models\articlesmodel.php
Line: 8
Function: where

Comment: @Gias on the login model on my answer change the return `$query->result();` to `return $query->row();`

Comment: Thank sir, problem solved, this is my fault because there is a problem in article database entry

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['encryption_key'] = '1234';
```

That isn't going to work because CodeIgniter has requirements for it's encryption_key. See the docs here.

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/encryption.html

Try this

```
$key = $this->encryption->create_key(16);
```

And then use that key below

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'YOUR KEY';
```

Alternatively, and even better, here's two websites that will generate CodeIgniter encryption keys for you.

http://jeffreybarke.net/tools/codeigniter-encryption-key-generator/

http://randomkeygen.com/

Comment: Think there is a bit more causing his issue.